# sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper() TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable when using

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am learning how to integrate `spark` with `kafka`. Currently i created a `virtualenv` and installed `pyspark`, `py4j` packages.

I also configured these environment:

1. PYSPARK_PYTHON  :  `C:\learn_new\learn_utils\venv\Scripts\python.exe`
2. SPARK_HOME      :  `C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7`

Then i want to run the example python source code under `C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\examples\src\main\python\streaming\direct_kafka_wordcount.py`

The script code is this:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import sys


    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
    from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        if len(sys.argv) != 3:
            print("Usage: direct_kafka_wordcount.py <broker_list> <topic>", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(-1)

    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The command line to run the python code under `virtualenv` is this:

```
python --default --client --host localhost --port 60614 c:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\examples\src\main\python\streaming\direct_kafka_wordcount.py kafka_host_name:9092 topic_name
```

Then i got this error:

```
    File "c:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\examples\src\main\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py", line 138, in createDirectStream
        helper = KafkaUtils._get_helper(ssc._sc)
    File "c:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\examples\src\main\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py", line 217, in _get_helper
        return sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper()
    TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

What's the issue of it?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Just a guess but do you have Java 8 installed?

Comment: yes, installed. 'java -version' shows 'java version 1.8.0_211'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mainly want to debug code locally, so i do not want to use spark-submit and add --jars 
 or --packages parameters to run the code.

But it really need the spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.3.jar package.(here change the package version according to your spark version)

So i tried to download the package and save it to the C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars(change it to your spark installation path, and find the jars folder).

Then the issue is solved. Hope it will help other people.

Comment: Note add the packages to other brokers in the cluster. If it has error about missing any java packages, try to download other jar package as this.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, just added the jar separately to two places one where spark had all its jars. Secondly, added the jar into jars of pyspark which was kept at a different location inside the present python version. And it worked